# Is it considered bad practice to create subclasses in Java to change annotations?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

For example, when writing JPA or Hibernate code, I might want to create a descendant of a domain class, say Account.  The descended version represents the a form a show the user.  The form only has about half the fields that are on Account.  So the object I use to hold the form value should not change the other fields.

Is using inheritance to change annotations considered bad?  Assuming it is not, are there any good short hands or design patterns for doing it better or more effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the case you describe here (at least how I understood it) would not be a good candidate for creating subclasses.

Basically you want to restrict the form to change only some fields/associations of an entity, right? I further assume that you don't trust the developer of the form that only the fields that should be editable are changed, hence the requirement to restrict that.

In that case, one option might be to use the [DTO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (data transfer object): create a DTO for the form data and let the user fill its fields. Then pass the DTO to a service which updates the entity accordingly. This way you have control of which fields are editable and how the update is performed.

Another way might be to create a wrapper for the entity that throws exceptions when a setter for an uneditable field is invoked. However, that would be a runtime solution and I'd prefer the DTO approach here.

*Edit*:

some reasons why inheritance might prove problematic in this case:

- The subclasses don't represent entities, however, you'd still have to represent the subclasses on the database (either through discriminators or additional tables)
- An entity that is created by that form would always have the subclass and thus would not be editable in other places (unless you mess with the database etc.)
- Entities are data containers and should not depend on the presentation. Hence having a special entity (subclass) for one UI usecase (the form in your case) would violate the single responsibility principle and abstraction between model/data and view/presentation layer.